# Heroku seems to keep some kind of cache when it tries to build the application

Tags: heroku, npm, node-modules

I have an application nodejs published inside Heroku. It was all working, but after some time without changes, today I had to publish a new feature which include updates from some node packages and as always I just did `git push heroku master` to publish those changes.

But the building it's always failing giving me the follow error:

```
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.11.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   5.6.0
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.11.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.11.1...
remote:        npm 5.6.0 already installed with node
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Caching has been disabled because NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Prebuild
remote:        Running heroku-prebuild
remote:
remote:        > my-api@0.0.3 heroku-prebuild /tmp/build_4bf4fa86ec647a2cc30bb6373298f732
remote:        > npm install --only=dev
remote:
remote:
remote:        > husky@2.5.0 install /tmp/build_4bf4fa86ec647a2cc30bb6373298f732/node_modules/husky
remote:        > node husky install
remote:
remote: module.js:549
remote:     throw err;
remote:     ^
remote:
remote: Error: Cannot find module 'cross-spawn'
remote:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
remote:     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
remote:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
remote:     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_4bf4fa86ec647a2cc30bb6373298f732/node_modules/execa/index.js:4:20)
remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
remote:     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
remote:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! husky@2.5.0 install: `node husky install`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the husky@2.5.0 install script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.s1wgX/_logs/2019-06-29T14_51_08_120Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! my-api@0.0.3 heroku-prebuild: `npm install --only=dev`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the my-api@0.0.3 heroku-prebuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.s1wgX/_logs/2019-06-29T14_51_08_638Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to my-api-api-staging.
```

Some considerations

1. I've been always `npm install --only=dev`, because I want!
2. I'm not using the `cross-spawn` package
3. Inside `husky` package there's nothing about `cross-spawn`
4. I tried to add `cross-spawn`, but the error keeps on
5. NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false // never changed, and always worked
6. NODE_ENV=production // never changed, and always worked

After many builds trying to make this work (and still), I notice this

1. My current package.json `"version": "0.0.7",` and Heroku it's showing `my-api@0.0.3`
2. I have tried change the `heroku-prebuild` to something else and Heroku it's showing `Running heroku-prebuild... npm install --only=dev`, always.

So, I guess this is some kind of cache, right?!

What could be happening?

Comment: "Caching has been disabled because NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false", so I don't think so.

Comment: "I've been always `npm install --only=dev`, because I want!" Do you have a better reason than "because I want"? This is super weird in production. Also, please show us your `package.json`.